# inner join shows same table for comments

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

I need to grab the comments that a user started and which were answered by him.
I'm trying to `inner join` below, but he repeats the result.
I need to show the User's comment that he started with the answers, and both he replied.

```
select *
from comments as comment
join comments as parent
on comment.user_parent_id = parent.user_id
where comment.member = 123
```

```
user_id | user_fname | user_lname | user_parent_id | member
1       | test 1     | xx         | 1              | 123
2       | test 2     | xx         |                |
3       | test 3     | xx         |                |
4       | test 4     | xx         | 1              | 123
```

Comment: it looks like you are trying to join comment to itself? do you mean `join parent as parent on...`?

Comment: I'm trying to do a join on the same table

Comment: if the data is on the same table, then what is the purpose of the join?

Comment: is a system of comments and reply and need to show both that 'user X' started and he responded in the comments of the 'user Y'

Comment: To find posts a user (id 937) has authored: `SELECT * FROM comments WHERE 937 IN (user_id, user_parent_id);`

Comment: What fields do you have in the table and what do they mean?

Comment: @gvee, I will test now

Comment: 1) userA make ​​a comment. 2) userB replied to comment from userA. 3) userB replied to comment userA again. 4) userB make ​​a new comment... I need to list the comments userB as a group, show the comment he made and comment with the answer userA

Comment: is easier to imagine how a conversation

Comment: Please provide an example of your desired results.

Comment: suppose a conversation between me and you: #1 conversation: you write and I answer. #2 conversation: you write 3 times and 2 times I answer
#3 Talk: I write and you answered. the result should be 3 conversations... see how the facebook wall that shows what has been posted and commented. thanks

Comment: I created a new field called 'keys' and a select group and recover without repetition: `SELECT keys from comments where author = 1979 GROUP BY keys`, then I use another loop and select to group the comments and responses that share the same 'keys': `SELECT * from comments where keys = $ comment['keys']`... is working, but is it the best way?

Answer (score -1):

You can make a recursive SQL function, use a hierarchycal index (SQL Server) or make a loop "while has parent".

Comment: This is better fit as a comment not an answer. Please update your answer to fit the guidelines for answering. Refer to : [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)